# Things go wrong when trying to insert button? (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, swiftui

I am transitioning to SwiftUI from UIKit and not sure why I get an error at the VStack declaration line, "Static member 'leading' cannot be used on instance of type 'HorizontalAlignment' ". This only happens when I insert the button, there is no error when I comment the button lines of the code out.

```
import SwiftUI
import SQLite3

struct SearchCustomers: View {
@State private var first_name: String = ""
@State private var last_name: String = ""
@State private var customerNumber: Int = 0
var customers: [Customer] = []
//var db: SQLiteDatabase
// File path -> /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/classicmodels.sqlite

// dummy data to remove later
let customer1 = Customer(customerNumber: 12, customerName: "A", contactLastName: "A",  contactFirstName: "A", phone: "A", addressLine1: "A", addressLine2: "A", city: "A", state: "A", postalCode: "A", country: "A", salesRepEmployeeNumber: 12, creditLimit: 12.35)


// Dictionary to store search results from sqlite
var search_results: [String: String] = [:]
// var customerDB =  SQLiteDatabase.open(path: "")


var body: some View {

    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Search by name").font(Font.title.weight(.regular))
        HStack {
            Text("First Name")
            TextField("Enter text", text: $first_name)
            Text("Last Name")
            TextField("Enter text", text: $last_name)
        }

        Button(action: {
            // open connection to the db
            do {
                let db = try SQLiteDatabase.open(path: "/Users/macbookpro/Downloadsclassicmodels.sqlite")
                print("opened connection")

            } catch {
                print("Unable to open db connection.")
            }
        }, label: {
            Text("Search for customer")
        })

        Spacer()
        Spacer()
        Text("Search by customer number").font(Font.title.weight(.regular))
        HStack {
            Text("Customer Number: ")
            TextField("Enter text", text: $first_name)
        }
        Spacer()
        Spacer()
        Spacer()
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Query Results").font(Font.title.weight(.light))
            List {
                ForEach(customers, id: \.customerNumber) { customer in
                    Text("customer")
                }
            }
        }

    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Search for Customers")
   }

  }

struct SearchCustomers_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
       SearchCustomers()
   }
}
```

Comment: I keep running into this problem too. It basically means that you have a compile error -somewhere else-, but the SwiftUI compiler is screwing it up and giving you a false error. The only way I've figured out how to find it is to comment out parts of the code until the error goes away or until the real error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 4/10/20:**
The problem is that you have more than 10 children of your `VStack`, and it only accepts up to 10. To solve the problem, stick some subviews in a `Group`, which has no visual effect but allows the `VStack` to work:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SQLite3

struct SearchCustomers: View {
@State private var first_name: String = ""
@State private var last_name: String = ""
@State private var customerNumber: Int = 0
var customers: [Customer] = []
//var db: SQLiteDatabase
// File path -> /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/classicmodels.sqlite

// dummy data to remove later
let customer1 = Customer(customerNumber: 12, customerName: "A", contactLastName: "A",  contactFirstName: "A", phone: "A", addressLine1: "A", addressLine2: "A", city: "A", state: "A", postalCode: "A", country: "A", salesRepEmployeeNumber: 12, creditLimit: 12.35)


// Dictionary to store search results from sqlite
var search_results: [String: String] = [:]
// var customerDB =  SQLiteDatabase.open(path: "")


var body: some View {

    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Search by name").font(Font.title.weight(.regular))
        HStack {
            Text("First Name")
            TextField("Enter text", text: $first_name)
            Text("Last Name")
            TextField("Enter text", text: $last_name)
        }

        Button(action: {
            // open connection to the db
            do {
                let db = try SQLiteDatabase.open(path: "/Users/macbookpro/Downloadsclassicmodels.sqlite")
                print("opened connection")

            } catch {
                print("Unable to open db connection.")
            }
        }) {
            Text("Search for customer")
        }

        Group {
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
            Text("Search by customer number").font(Font.title.weight(.regular))
            HStack {
                Text("Customer Number: ")
                TextField("Enter text", text: $first_name)
            }
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
            Spacer()
        }
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Query Results").font(Font.title.weight(.light))
            List {
                ForEach(customers, id: \.customerNumber) { customer in
                    Text("customer")
                }
            }
        }

    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Search for Customers")
   }

  }

struct SearchCustomers_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
       SearchCustomers()
   }
}
```

In future versions of Swift, the compiler is being improved so that errors like these will be easier to diagnose, but here's the answer for this one for now.

Original answer preserved below for posterity:

---

I've had quite a few instances of that error when the real problem is completely separate. In this case, I would suggest changing your `Button` code to this:

```swift
Button(action: {
    // open connection to the db
    do {
        let db = try SQLiteDatabase.open(path: "/Users/macbookpro/Downloadsclassicmodels.sqlite")
        print("opened connection")
    } catch {
        print("Unable to open db connection.")
    }
}) {
    Text("Search for customer")
}
```

(moving the label into a trailing closure, because this seems to work better for me). That makes your code this:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SQLite3

struct SearchCustomers: View {
@State private var first_name: String = ""
@State private var last_name: String = ""
@State private var customerNumber: Int = 0
var customers: [Customer] = []
//var db: SQLiteDatabase
// File path -> /Users/macbookpro/Downloads/classicmodels.sqlite

// dummy data to remove later
let customer1 = Customer(customerNumber: 12, customerName: "A", contactLastName: "A",  contactFirstName: "A", phone: "A", addressLine1: "A", addressLine2: "A", city: "A", state: "A", postalCode: "A", country: "A", salesRepEmployeeNumber: 12, creditLimit: 12.35)


// Dictionary to store search results from sqlite
var search_results: [String: String] = [:]
// var customerDB =  SQLiteDatabase.open(path: "")


var body: some View {

    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Search by name").font(Font.title.weight(.regular))
        HStack {
            Text("First Name")
            TextField("Enter text", text: $first_name)
            Text("Last Name")
            TextField("Enter text", text: $last_name)
        }

        Button(action: {
            // open connection to the db
            do {
                let db = try SQLiteDatabase.open(path: "/Users/macbookpro/Downloadsclassicmodels.sqlite")
                print("opened connection")

            } catch {
                print("Unable to open db connection.")
            }
        }) {
            Text("Search for customer")
        }

        Spacer()
        Spacer()
        Text("Search by customer number").font(Font.title.weight(.regular))
        HStack {
            Text("Customer Number: ")
            TextField("Enter text", text: $first_name)
        }
        Spacer()
        Spacer()
        Spacer()
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Query Results").font(Font.title.weight(.light))
            List {
                ForEach(customers, id: \.customerNumber) { customer in
                    Text("customer")
                }
            }
        }

    }
    .navigationBarTitle("Search for Customers")
   }

  }

struct SearchCustomers_Previews: PreviewProvider {
   static var previews: some View {
       SearchCustomers()
   }
}
```

I don't think this is actually your problem, but rather a bug in SwiftUI. Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried implementing your suggestion but I'm still getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: @ganele892 If you're still looking for an answer, I solved it